# Using malloc() and sizeof() to create a struct on the heap

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use malloc() and sizeof() to create a struct on the heap. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee
{
    char first[21];
    char last[21];
    char title[21];
    int salary;
};


struct Employee* createEmployee(char* first, char* last, char* title, int salary) // Creates a struct Employee object on the heap.
{
    struct Employee* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee)); 

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(p->first, first);
        strcpy(p->last, last);
        strcpy(p->title, title);
        p->salary, salary;
    }
    return p;

}
```

No my compiler (Visual C++) tells me for the line `struct Employee* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));` that the type "void *" can't be converted to the type "Employee *". I don't know what is wrong here. Seems as if struct Employee is a void but i don't understand why...

Comment: Just as a general tip, when the compiler tells you that a type can't be converted to another type, it usually means that the right hand side of your assignment is not the same type as your left hand side, not the other way around.  So, that error is telling you that your right hand side is the wrong type.  That should help you narrow it down in the future.

Comment: Apart from the allocation etc issue, note that `p->salary, salary;` is probably not what you want.

Comment: @claguardia: That's decent advice in general, but irrelevant to OP's problem. OP's problem is basically the C,C++ equivalent of writing `#!/usr/bin/perl` at the top of a Bourne shell script.

Comment: How exactly is explaining a compile error irrelavent?

Comment: The right-hand side is not the wrong type in this case.

Comment: void * != Employee *.  Are you also going to tell me apple = orange or 3 = 2?

Comment: @claguardia: no, he wants to make you aware of the difference between C and C++ language semantics

Comment: I don't see what you mean here.  Even in c, the types are still different.  Its just not enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @claguardia: the point is not type equality, but implicit conversion of `void *`, which is present in C, but not in C++; the type of the right-hand side is not 'wrong', because the C standard says so

Comment: LEARN WHAT Language you are using. Not C++. If you are only going to write C have the wits to use the C compiler to build it. Then you would not have had these problems. Or a better solution (learn how to use C++ and create a constructor).

Comment: @Crishtoph: Thats true, you just said what I said. But he was using a C++ compiler to compile c, so I don't see how this argument has any relevance in the first place. I explained a C++ compile error. Was it relevant? Yes, because that was his compile error. The right hand side was the wrong type. The original comment that this wasn't relevent was stupid in the fist place. The fact that c++ insists on an explicit cast is more of a feature then a semantic difference considering the C++ standard maintains that C code is compilable on it (though across compilers, this tends to not be the case).

Comment: The C++ standard does not claim to maintain compatibility with C, and in fact it has many syntactic and semantic differences.

Comment: the question was originally tagged C, and the code is obviously C as well (as we've seen, it doesn't compile as C++); the 'correct' answer would be to either translate the code to C++ (ie use a constructor) or to enable C mode in Visual C++ (which is Microsoft's C90 compiler as well as it's C++ compiler)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++ (since you are using Visual C++ to compile), you have to explicitly cast the pointer returned by `malloc`:

```
struct Employee* p = (struct Employee*) malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

Comment: Don't tell me Visual C++ isn't capable of compiling C code as C code?

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. I will accept your answer when the timer is ready.

Comment: @aschepler: It's capable of doing it but it doesn't do it by default unless the file has a `.c` extension.

Comment: @schepler It is, but I forget the flags/settings off the top of my head.

Comment: If this is C code, **do not** write useless and harmful casts to make a C++ compiler happy. Fix your IDE's settings to tell it you're writing C and not C++.

Comment: @R.. I'll agree with most of what you said, but I'm interested to know why you believe this specific case is harmful.

Comment: @user470379: See my answer. In C, casting the return value of `malloc` is harmful because it hides warnings if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise prototype `malloc`. It also makes your code harder to maintain; your solution requires making 3 changes if the type of `p` changes, while my answer requires a change only in one place. Finally, new C programmers should **not** get in the bad habit of using casts whenever they see a compiler warning or error. This usually just buries bugs. Correct code almost never requires casts, and their use should be seen as a code smell.

Comment: Billy ONeal, also you can force it to compile any file as C or C++ (regardless of the file extension) using the switch /TP for C++ or TC for C (or right clicking on the file -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile AS

Answer (score 11):

Best practices for using `malloc`:

```
struct Employee *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

You also need to fix your IDE/compiler to tell it you're writing C and not C++, since it's too broken to figure this out on its own...

Since some people seem unhappy with this answer (and with my disapproval of the other answers), I think I should explain why working around the problem is not good.

In C, casting the return value of malloc is harmful because it hides warnings if you forgot to include stdlib.h or otherwise prototype malloc. It also makes your code harder to maintain; all the answers with a cast require making 3 changes if the type of p needs to be changed, while my answer requires a change only in one place. Finally, new C programmers should not get in the bad habit of using casts whenever they see a compiler warning or error. This usually just buries bugs. Correct code almost never requires casts, and their use should be seen as a code smell

Comment: To the downvoter, "retaliating" for -1 on a bad answer you gave is really mature...

Comment: The downvoter is me, and the downvote was partly on the (lack of) merit of your answer and partly because I believe that downvoting *all* of the existing answers (including mine) was really bad form. Care to discuss?

Comment: When all the existing answers are repeats of the same thing, and all are ignoring OP's real problem (compiling as the wrong language) and giving an ugly workaround, what would be better than downvoting them all? Just downvoting the first one? Minding my own business?

Comment: @R..: considering that maybe the assumption that only you seemed to make was wrong, and seeking to clarify first?

Comment: What assumption is that? The assumption that OP tagged the question in the correct language he intends to use?

Comment: @R..: yeah, that one. Hints: the OP has 160 rep, doesn't recognize a beginner issue, and some of their questions use "c/c++" in their title in a manner that makes you think that maybe they don't really know that C is not C++. If that's still not convincing, have a look at the accepted answer up there.

Comment: Very well. I've fixed the tagging in the question, but I still consider the accepted answer bad advice. If you're writing C++ you should use `new`, not `malloc`. If you're writing C, you should never write casts like this.

Comment: @R..: the funny thing about the tagging is that I had changed it before all this started, but Billy (previous rev than you) reverted it. Oh well.

Comment: "A C++ question should not mention malloc. – R.."

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the result of malloc to the type of pointer you are using.

```
struct Employee* p = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

`malloc` will always return a chunck of memory as a `(void *)`.  Its up to you to tell the compiler what type of chunck that memory is.

Comment: No, OP should either fix the settings of his IDE/compiler or fix his question to tag it C++ rather than C, if he really intends to use C++ (but why would you use `malloc` in C++?!)

Comment: Its not a settings issue.  If his file is .c, then it will compile with the c compiler.  If its a .cpp, it will compile with the c++ compiler.  Its valid to write c and compile it with a c++ compiler, but types are a enforced just a bit more by the compiler.

Comment: It is not valid to write C and compile it with a C++ compiler. It's only valid to write a particular subset of C (the intersection of C and C++) if you're going to do that, and it will require you to write very bad C code.

Comment: Not true.  A c++ compiler is specified such that it is supposed to be able to compile all c.  The fact that some c++ compilers do not properly compile c is the fault of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling as C code, that line should be valid.

But in C++, the conversion from `void*` to `Employee*` is invalid.

Is the file named something.c?  Are there compiler options you can change?

If you must use a C++ compiler, you can fix this by adding an explicit cast:

```
struct Employee* p = (struct Employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `malloc` is a `void*`. The value you want to assign to `p` must be of type `Employee*`. In C++ (in contrast to C), there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to another pointer type. Therefore, you need to perform the conversion explicitly:

```
struct Employee* p = reinterpret_cast<Employee*>(malloc(sizeof(struct Employee)));
```

Comment: Question is tagged C, not C++

Comment: @R..: Is there a good reason to assume that the OP meant to confuse us by using VC++ (and mentioning it explicitly) rather than that they simply mistagged the question, other than "my assumption is better than your assumption"? I would think that by accepting the answer he did, he kind of agrees that this is a C++ question.

Comment: A C++ question should not mention `malloc`.