# How to use cast and pointers with malloc and sizeof

Tags: casting, malloc, sizeof

I am confused about when to use a cast with malloc in C. What is the difference between these 2 pieces of code (the code in question is the function that initializes a linked list):

1st Excerpt:

```
  struct QueueNode {
  char content;
  struct QueueNode* prev;
  struct QueueNode* next;
 };

  struct Queue{
  struct QueueNode* first;
 struct QueueNode* last;
};
```

Initialisation of the Queue:

```
Queue* queueCreate() {
Queue* q = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
q->first = NULL;
q->last = NULL;
return q;
```

}

2nd excerpt:

```
typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element

 {
 int number;
 Element *next;

 };

typedef struct List List;
struct List
{
 Element *first;
};
```

Initialisation of the Queue:

```
List *initialisation()
{
List *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
Element *element = malloc(sizeof(*element));

if (l == NULL || element == NULL)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

element->number = 0;
element->next = NULL;
l->first = element;

return l;

 }
```

This is what I don't understand:
why in the first excerpt do we use a cast (Queue*):

```
 Queue* q = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

while in the 2nd excerpt, there is no cast but we pass a pointer (*l) to sizeof, and there's no cast?

```
Liste *l = malloc(sizeof(*l))
```

So I guess the problem is when to use the cast and when to pass a pointer to the sizeof function.

ps. I read some answers here on so like this one [Using malloc() and sizeof() to create a struct on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519834/using-malloc-and-sizeof-to-create-a-struct-on-the-heap)

it's about c++ and it says you have to add a cast. In C, does the cast depend on the type of implementation?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The cast isn't needed in both cases. It's probably an oversight that the two examples are not identical in this aspect.